What is this 90s Cyberpunk themed cartoon?
I'm looking for the name of a Saturday morning American cartoon from the 90s with a distinctly Cyberpunk theme. The villain is a corporate CEO type guy, who I believe wore a black suit, and had black hair and a goatee. The protagonists are a punk-rock girl with pink(?) hair and fishnet stockings, a man-size talking Tyrannosaurus Rex, and a stretchy guy who acts as comic relief.
Whenever I search for "cyberpunk cartoon" all I can ever find is Aeon Flux and anime. It is neither of those.

You're looking for Project G.e.e.K.e.R. from 1996:

Set in the future, the show was based around a genetic shapeshifter experiment known as Project GKR (Geno-Kinetic Research), who had been stolen by Lady MacBeth (a short-tempered female cyborg with a bionic arm) before he could get the programming he needed to be a deadly and powerful weapon at the hands of the evil Mister Moloch, head of Moloch Industries. Due to the lack of his final programming, "Geeker" is left to be a totally random, permanently salivating, four-fingered klutz. He only occasionally manages to use his powers to any full extent, a blessing and a threat to his friends and their enemies. Lady MacBeth and her partner-in-crime Noah (a green, baseball cap wearing and intelligent Tyrannosaurus rex) must now prevent Moloch and Geeker's creator Dr. Maston from ever obtaining Geeker at all costs.

The villain has black hair and wears a business suit, and you've described the other characters well (though Lady MacBeth is a bit off, she doesn't have pink hair). Here are the protagonists:

Here's the intro:



